# Split a row in excel wrt to its corresponding column values using Python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have an CSV row and column in below format :-

```
FileName           Coordinates
abc.txt            0 0.41, 0.42, 0.44, 0.56
                   0 0.55, 0.67, 0.68, 0.89
```

I want output in below form :-

```
abc.txt           0 0.41, 0.42, 0.44, 0.56
abc.txt           0 0.55, 0.67, 0.68, 0.89
```

The code I have tried is mentioned below

```
df = pd.read_csv('/home/sourabh.raj/Documents/Sample_test_1.csv')
df.drop('Coordinates', axis=1).join(df['Coordinates'].str.split('\n', expand=True).stack().reset_index(level=1, drop=True).rename('Coordinates'))
print(df)
```

But this above code is not working.

Looking for your help.[I have added the image as well](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bW9Cw.png)

Comment: does`ffill` solve your problem? `df['FileName'].fillna(method='ffill')`

Comment: @MohamedThasinah no it still gives the same results.

Comment: store the result either use inplace or save on save column?

Comment: I have just now saw the update image. filla dosn't help u.

Comment: @MohamedThasinah - I tried as you said with this df['FileName'].fillna(method='ffill',inplace=True) and yet I got the same results.

Comment: you can convert coordinates into list then explode the list column. you will get your desired resu;t

Comment: df.coords.str.split('\n+').apply(pd.Series).stack()\
                  .str.split(expand=True).applymap(float).values.tolist() - you mean this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this,

```
df['Coordinates'] = df['Coordinates'].str.split('\n')
print(df.explode('Coordinates').reset_index(drop=True))
```

O/P:

```
  FileName               Coordinates
0  abc.txt  0 0.41, 0.42, 0.44, 0.56
1  abc.txt  0 0.55, 0.67, 0.68, 0.89
```

Explanation:

Convert coordinates into list then explode the list column and Reset your index values.